# Create a subdomain for my domain

Tags: apache, redirect, nginx, port, gitlab

I have a server of **OVH** company and I'm having some problems **setting a subdomain** for it.

My **server configuration** is something like this:

- **Apache** service working at **port 80** with the website and works only with https (apache config makes a redirection for http request to https).
- **PostgreSQL** service on default **port 5432**
- **Gitlab** installation working over nginx at **port 81**.

I'm trying to set the *external_url* for gitlab to http://git.example.com:81 but when I try to access, i'm being redirected to a OVH default page.

I can access gitlab if I set the external url to something like http://example.com:81 or even if I set a relative path like http://example.com:81/gitlab but I can't make it work with the subdomain http://git.example.com:81

How do you think I can get it working? Maybe I have to change DNS zone or something related to the redirections in the OVH web manager panel??

Thanks in advance! This is a really great community!

Comment: You have to confirm that IP of `git.example.com` is the gitlab server. check the answer section of `dig git.example.com`.

Comment: And also you might want to migrate this question to http://serverfault.com/ since this question is not so related to programming.

Comment: how can i migrate this question to serverfault?

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I just assign in the panel of the web hosting this redirection: git.example.com => example.com and that does the trick.